# Search within Soundcloud with c#

Tags: c#, api, search, soundcloud

I'm trying to figure out how you search for tracks within the Soundcloud API.

I may have searched the wrong things, but I've looked in Soundclouds API page and haven't found anything that would help me.

I already have registered my app, so that isn't a problem. But how do you search for tracks?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Yeah I have. But from what I get from it, it's only relevant when you're using ruby etc (which has sdk's)

Answer (score 1):

With API, you gotta know what you are searching for – users, tracks or playlists etc. Go here – http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> for “search”. Then you can see the endpoints that accept `q` parameter – it stands for “query”.

Then all you need to do is issue an HTTP request to that certain endpoint with `q` parameter. Something like `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=love&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`;

Of course, in order to interact with the API you need to have the API client id.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting an error: (401) Unauthorized. Even though I am authorized. I have also tried connecting with an account. Still doesn't work.

Comment: awesome, then we can use own code to scraps records.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append the client id for each request

Answer (score 0):

You can get sounds in xml files with simple query :

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.xml?q=galiya&client_id=[client_id]
```

for json simple replace xml with json.